# Really Confused On How to Interact With GUI Input

Tags: java, user-interface, inheritance

I'm working on a nine men morris project for my CS class and I am not sure on how to interact with the GUI input via multiple classes. I have a morris board class that set ups the board with an actionListener that sets the color of the button when clicked, and I have a main game class that sets up the board. I'm not really sure how to articulate my question but basically I want to extend the actionListener to check if any mills are formed or what phase the game is currently in. I assumed the object-oriented approach to this would be putting a checkMillFormed() and checkPhase() method in the main game class as I want to make the board as dumb as possible, but I really not sure on how to go about doing this.

```
public class GameGUI extends JFrame implements MorrisGameListener {

    private MorrisBoardGUI Morrisboard;
    

    
    public GameGUI() {
        this.setUpDisplay();
    }
    
    private void setUpDisplay() {
        this.setSize(600, 700);
        this.setResizable(false);
        
        this.Morrisboard = new MorrisBoardGUI();
        
        this.add( this.Morrisboard );
    
        
    }
    
    public boolean checkMillFormed(int row, int column) {
        
        
    }
    
    public boolean checkPhase() {
        
    }
    

}

public class MorrisBoardGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {
    
    private JButton[][] board;
    private boolean player1;
    private int index;
    
    private JButton button7a;
    private JButton button7d;
    private JButton button7g;
    private JButton button6b;
    private JButton button6d;
    private JButton button6f;
    private JButton button5c;
    private JButton button5d;
    private JButton button5e;
    private JButton button4a;
    private JButton button4b;
    private JButton button4c;
    private JButton button4e;
    private JButton button4f; 
    private JButton button4g;
    private JButton button3c;
    private JButton button3d; 
    private JButton button3e;
    private JButton button2b;
    private JButton button2d; 
    private JButton button2f;
    private JButton button1a; 
    private JButton button1d; 
    private JButton button1g; 
    
    private JButton newGameButton;
    private JButton quitButton;
    
    
    public MorrisBoardGUI() {
        
        player1 = true;
        this.createBoard(); 
        
        this.board = new JButton[7][7];
        board[0] = new JButton[] {button7a, null, null, button7d, null, null, button7g};
        board[1] = new JButton[] {null, button6b, null, button6d, null,  button6f, null};
        board[2] = new JButton[] {null, null, button5c, button5d, button5e, null, null};
        board[3] = new JButton[] {button4a, button4b, button4c, null, button4e, button4f, button4g};
        board[4] = new JButton[] {null, null, button3c, button3d, button3e, null, null};
        board[5] = new JButton[] {null, button2b, null, button2d, null, button2f, null};
        board[6] = new JButton[] {button1a, null, null, button1d, null, null, button1g};
        
    
        
    }
    
    
    private JButton createPoint(int x, int y) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(x, y, 20, 20);
        button.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        this.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        return button;
    }
    
    private void createBoard() {
        
        this.setBackground(new Color(250, 247, 158));
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setLayout(null);
        
        button7a = createPoint(50, 50);
        button7d = createPoint(275, 50);
        button7g = createPoint(500, 50);
        button6b = createPoint(105, 150);
        button6d = createPoint(275, 150);
        button6f = createPoint(445, 150);
        button5c = createPoint(200, 225);
        button5d = createPoint(275, 225);
        button5e = createPoint(350, 225);
        button4a = createPoint(50, 275);
        button4b = createPoint(105, 275);
        button4c = createPoint(200, 275);
        button4e = createPoint(350, 275);
        button4f = createPoint(445, 275);
        button4g = createPoint(500, 275);
        button3c = createPoint(200, 325);
        button3d = createPoint(275, 325);
        button3e = createPoint(350, 325);
        button2b = createPoint(105, 400);
        button2d = createPoint(275, 400);
        button2f = createPoint(445, 400);
        button1a = createPoint(50, 500);
        button1d = createPoint(275, 500);
        button1g = createPoint(500, 500);
        
        newGameButton = new JButton("NEW");
        newGameButton.setBounds(235, 600, 50, 50);
        newGameButton.setMargin( new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0) );
        this.add(newGameButton);
        
        quitButton = new JButton("QUIT");
        quitButton.setBounds(285, 600, 50, 50);
        quitButton.setMargin( new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.add(quitButton);
        
    }
    
    public JButton[][] getBoard() {
        
        return this.board;
        
    }
    
    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(60, 60, 450, 450);
        g.drawRect(115, 160, 340, 250);
        g.drawRect(210, 235, 150, 100);
        g.drawLine(50, 285, 200, 285);
        g.drawLine(350, 285, 500, 285);
        g.drawLine(285, 60, 285, 235);
        g.drawLine(285, 335, 285, 500);
        
        
    }
    
    
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        for(int r = 0; r < this.board.length; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < this.board[r].length; c++) {
                
                JButton clickedButton = this.board[r][c];
                if(clickedButton == e.getSource() && player1 == false) {
                    
                    if(clickedButton.getBackground() == Color.LIGHT_GRAY) {
                    clickedButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    player1 = true;
                }
                
                else if(clickedButton == e.getSource() && player1 == true) {
                    
                    if(clickedButton.getBackground() == Color.LIGHT_GRAY) {
                    clickedButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                    player1 = false;
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've asked quite the question that doesn't have a simple answer.  I agree that you want the board to know as little as possible.  I would recommend that you start researching and reading about the [Model, View, Controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern and then reading about [Event Driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

Comment: While MVC is a well known and often used design pattern, I would argue that it is not really object oriented. (You can implement it with object oriented languages, but also with other approaches.) To get more into the object oriented way of thinking, you should enumerate some "real life" objects: you have a board, two players and maybe some kind of referee that decides, what is a mill. (In MVC, this all would be split up into model and controller probably.) Still the hint on event driven programming from @hooknc is also essential in my opinion.